# How to apply update_role (or a step) function from recipes to multiple columns

Tags: r, r-recipes, tidymodels

I'm using the `recipes` package from `tidymodels`. I'm trying to `update_role` for a few columns at the same time.  Example:

```
library(recipes)
library(dplyr)

cols_to_update = list()
cols_to_update[["a"]] <- c("mpg", "cyl")

mtcars %>% 
    recipe() %>% 
    update_role(cols_to_update[["a"]], new_role = "new_role")
```

I get error `Error: Not all functions are allowed in step function selectors (e.g.`c`). See ?selections.`
Here's [documentation for selections](https://tidymodels.github.io/recipes/reference/selections.html).
There's no way I can type all of them by hand.

Comment: Try `update_role(mpg, cyl, new_role = "new_role")`. This just lists the variables, no need for `c()`, like the error message says.

Comment: It works, thank you! But it's not what exactly I want. I already have a vector of column names saved to a variable. (I updated the code so you can see what I want). Is there a way to use/transform `cols_to_update` so it can be used as an input?

Comment: It worked with me: `update_role(cols_to_update, new_role = "new_role")`. I ran this with `cols_to_update <- c("mpg", "cyl")`.

Comment: Wow, ok. Works for me too. I wanted to make the example simpler but now it's too simple and it works. The thing is that I have a named list of vectors of variables. (I updated the example again.)

Comment: See if my answer below solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt at solving the question's problem using `purrr::map`. The code below works but maybe there are better ways.

```
library(recipes)
library(dplyr)

cols_to_update <- list()
cols_to_update[["a"]] <- c("mpg", "cyl")


purrr::map(cols_to_update, function(x){
  mtcars %>%
    recipe() %>%
    update_role(x, new_role = "new_role")
})
#$a
#Data Recipe
#
#Inputs:
#
#     role #variables
# new_role          2
#
#  9 variables with undeclared roles
```

**Edit.**

Here are two other examples, the first with base R `Map` and the other with `purrr::map`. They both give the same results.

The list `cols_to_update` now has 2 members, `"a"` and `"b"`.

```
cols_to_update[["b"]] <- c("disp", "wt", "carb")

Map(function(x, y){
  mtcars %>%
    recipe() %>%
    update_role(x, new_role = y)
}, cols_to_update, "new_role")

purrr::map(cols_to_update, function(x, y){
  mtcars %>%
    recipe() %>%
    update_role(x, new_role = y)
}, "new_role")
```